# Zend Framework 2 - Set CSV Separator

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, export-to-csv

I found this solution on how to render csv using zf2 here:
[Zend Framework 2 - Rendering CSV data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687720/zend-framework-2-rendering-csv-data)

The problem is the default separator is ','. I need to change it because some of the data content I'm rendering have commas in it.

My question is how do I change the default separator from ',' to tab or something else.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you constructing your CSV structured data in the first place?. The question you reference points only to the response headers and rendering but you need to provide a sample of how are you building the CSV content.

Comment: like this: $content = $val.','.$val2."\n";

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple solution to my problem. I just put each value inside " " so the commas would be ignored.

$content = '"'.$val.'","'.$val2.'"';