# Zend framework 2 CSV data as an array or string

Tags: zend-framework2

I am still very new to Zend and running into some issues on exporting my data to a CSV.

I found a great resource that explains the headers and download part [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687720/zend-framework-2-rendering-csv-data) however I am running into issues when trying to export the actual data.

If I create a variable like $content = "test" the export works fine using the code above.

However when I duplicate my indexAction code, make some changes, and bring it into my downloadAction, I am getting issues that I believe are due to my content being returned as an Object rather than an array or string.

My Module is grabbing the SQL by using:

```
public function fetchAllMembers($order = null , $order_by = null, $selectwhere = null) {
    $session = new SessionContainer('logggedin_user');
    $sql = new Sql($this->adapter);
    $select = new Select();

        $select->from(array('u' => 'tbl_all_data'));
        if ($selectwhere != null){
            $select->where($selectwhere);
        }
        $select->order($order_by . ' ' . $order);

    $selectString = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select);    
    $results = $this->adapter->query($selectString, Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
    $results->buffer();
    return $results;
}
```

and my Controller is calling that SQL by using:

```
 $content = $modulesTable->fetchAllMembers($order, $order_by, $where);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I don't need anyone to write the code for me just help with pointoing me in the right direction.

Comment: Neither you code nor the link shows how $content is assigned.

Comment: Prandeep, I just made a small edit, however you are correct.  $content is what I am trying to figure out.  As I mentioned, if I make $content = "test" my code works perfect and I get a CSV with the word Test.  What I am trying to figure out is how to make $content = an array with all my data which comes from fetchAllMembers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$this->adapter->query` returns a `Zend\Db\ResultSet` object. So you need to call `$results = $results->toArray();` to send an array.

Also you need to loop through the array and echo it out in your view file.

Answer (score 0):

Results, returned by adapter are [ResultSet](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.2/classes/Zend.Db.ResultSet.ResultSet.html) type. I guess you need to call at least

```
current()
```

method to grab some data. And they will be of array type, so, again you need to do something with them.
`toArray()` is often used to quickly get data.

More sophisticated way to get data, is to use `next()` method with `current()`:

```
$firstThing = $result->current();
$result->next();
$result->next();
$thirdThing = $result->current();
```

It's just an example, but it can be useful in some cases.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and I will look into this, however the other answer was exactly the call I needed.