# ZF2 file download not working

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am trying to download a file in ZF2 & stuck somewhere. I am not able to get the solution. The file is proper & readable. I think there's a problem in the header settings. Please help!. The excerpt code is as follows:

```
  $response = new \Zend\Http\Response\Stream();
        $response->setStream(
                fopen($filePath, 'r')
        );
        $response->setStatusCode(200);
        $headers = new \Zend\Http\Headers();
        $headers->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');


        $headers->addHeaderLine('Content-Transfer-Encoding','binary');
        $headers->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
        $headers->addHeaderLine(
                        'Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . $media->getName() . '"'
                )
                ->addHeaderLine(
                        'Content-Length', filesize($filePath)
        );

        $response->setHeaders($headers);

        return $response;
```

I have referred to the following:
[force download using ZF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219873/force-download-using-zf2) 
& 
[Zend Framework 2 - Rendering CSV data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687720/zend-framework-2-rendering-csv-data)

I am getting a corrupted file

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have two duplicated headers:

```
$headers->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not the issue unfortunately :(

Comment: Ohh! Sorry, forgot to mention the error properly.. I am getting a corrupted image after download..Attached the screenshot

Comment: Are you using the correct mime type for the file you expect? I see that's a JPEG image. Try using  `image/jpeg`

Comment: The content is dynamic(image/pdf/audio).  So, setting it to ` Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream' `

Comment: At which point do you read the file? It seems that there are two spaces at the beginning of the file: `starts with 0x20 0x20`. Maybe you should check the code that is reading the file.